# Custom html.html.twig for a display mode

Tags: 8, theming, display-suite

While using display suite in drupal 8.6.2 Is it possible to have a custom `displaymode-html.html.twig` that replaces the default
`html.html.twig`?

So far I have tried enabling the view mode dev hints in `themename.yml` but it doesn't seem to be showing me anything for `html.html.twig`

Comment: what is your propose of having a custom html.twig file? this file is not meant to be used for design proposes much, just placement of page , page bottom, page top and placeholders

Comment: The placement needs to vary, but only for certain display modes.

Comment: You don't have any theming variables in this file , even you have no access to regions , so how placement might vary when you only have page top which must be before page, page and page button which should be placed after page?

Comment: I think you should have use other theming files like page.html.twig not html.html.twig

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation that would cover this?

Comment: Also, js and css placeholders are in `html.html.twig` not sure how I'd be able to override them inside `page--viewmode.html.twig`

Comment: theming files act as hierarchical in html.html.twig you place page variable, then in page.html.twig you place regions placement, regions are places that blocks are placed and ...

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal is the drupal reference for learning how to theme, there are many more tutorials available, I highly recommend www.Drupalize.me but it is not free

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Display Suite but I'd recommend you to have a look at [hook_theme_suggestions_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) in order to build your own twig template suggestions based on specific conditions that you can set using the `$variables` variable values.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this with the hook set to `html` but it just shows me a blank in view mode.